# Get status between two arrays after a re-order using array index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a drop and drag quiz
arr1 moves with drag and drop    and arr2 is the correct array reference order

Objective when the array order of arr1 changes
I need to check the  reordered array indexes are the same as the ids in array2
by using somehow the re-ordered index of value1

so with the current status of arr1 with the comparison  items 0  and 4 should get the status correct

```
   I've had a go with if (value1.image=== value2.image && value1.$index=== value2.id)
```

to no avail

https://jsfiddle.net/ya29uLwd/1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the index with the id, noticing that the index is integer and the id in your array is string which you need to parse in order to check it properly.

the following is code

```
angular.forEach(arr1, function(value1, key1) {
    angular.forEach(arr2, function(value2, key2) {
        if (value1.image == value2.image && key1 == parseInt(value2.id)  ) {

    console.log(value2.status);
    
        }
    });
});
```